# Why doesn't the up/down counter count down?

Tags: verilog, counter

I was doing the Logic Design assignment, and I found some problems I can't solve.
I need to design a 6-bit counter, and this counter needs to count with two functions, for up and down respectively.
I have done the up part and down part, but when I run the simulation, the counting down part doesn't work correctly.
The function for counting down: the next a = a - 2^n, where n = 0, 1, 2, 3... eg. a1 = 63, a2 = 63 - 1 = 62, a3 = 62 - 2 = 60, a4 = 56...

But the simulation with my program, it becomes 63, 62, 61(63 - 2), 59(63 - 4)...

By the way, this assignment has a reset feature.
However, my program won't keep counting after being reset.
It should back to zero and continue counting theoretically.

The following is my code:

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps
module lab2_1(
    input clk,
    input rst,
    output reg [5:0] out
);
    reg [5:0] cnt;
    wire [5:0] cnt_next;
    reg updown;
    wire [5:0] out_next;
    initial begin
        out = 0;
        cnt = 1;
        updown = 1;
    end
    assign cnt_next = (out == 6'b111111) ? 0 : cnt + 1;
    assign out_next = out - (2**cnt);
    always @(*) begin
        if(out == 6'b111111)begin
            updown = 0;
        end
        if(out == 6'b000000)begin
            updown = 1;
        end
        if(rst == 1) begin
            out = 0;
            updown = 1;
            cnt = 0;
        end
    end
    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
        if(updown == 1)begin
            if(out > cnt)begin
                out <= out - cnt;
            end
            else
                out <= out + cnt;
        end
        else begin
            out <= out_next;
        end
        cnt <= cnt_next;
    end

endmodule
```

The testbench just monitors the output and drives the  inpupts.

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps
module lab2_1_t;

    wire [5:0] out;
    reg clk;
    reg rst;

    lab2_1 v(clk, rst, out);

    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        rst = 0;
        $monitor($time,":clk = %b, rst = %b, out = %d", clk, rst, out);
    end
    always #10 clk = ~clk;
    always #10000 rst = ~rst;

endmodule
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You should not make assignments to the same signal (such as `cnt`) from multiple blocks.  You can assign to `cnt` from a single `always` block.  I don't think you need both `out` and `cnt`.

Here is a simplified version which automatically switches between up and down:

```
module lab2_1(
    input clk,
    input rst,
    output reg [5:0] cnt
);
    reg updown;

    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
        if (rst) begin
            updown <= 1;
        end else if (cnt == 6'b111110) begin
            updown <= 0;
        end else if (cnt == 6'b000001) begin
            updown <= 1;
        end
    end

    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
        if (rst) begin
            cnt <= 0;
        end else if (updown) begin
            cnt <= cnt + 1;
        end else begin
            cnt <= cnt - 1;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

The code shows a more typical use of the reset signal in the sequential `always` block.  See also [for more examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog).

Here is a modified testbench where the reset is asserted at time 0, then released after a couple clock cycles.  At the end, it asserts reset again so you can see that the counter goes to 0.

```
module lab2_1_t;
    wire [5:0] out;
    reg clk;
    reg rst;

    lab2_1 v(clk, rst, out);

    initial begin
        $monitor($time,":clk = %b, rst = %b, out = %d", clk, rst, out);
        clk = 0;
        rst = 1;
        #40 rst = 0;
        #10000 rst = 1;
        #1000 $finish;
    end

    always #10 clk = ~clk;
endmodule
```